# chrome extension как открыть `popup` с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Столкнулся с проблемой.

Пытаюсь открыть окно расширения с помощью javascript, но не как не получается.

```
chrome.pageAction.show(tabID);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо что бы при конкретном условии окно автоматически открылось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `chrome.pageAction.show` не открывает popup расширения.
Данный метод предназначен для другого - он для добавления экшнов расширения (кнопок) на панель адресной строки браузера.

Открыть popup программно, из кода расширения - **невозможно**.
Это действие должно выполняться *пользователем*: либо кликом по кнопке расширения, либо нажатием комбинации клавиш на клавиатуре.

---

Когда нужно просто оповещать пользователя о чем-либо, прекрасным вариантом будет использование [API уведомлений](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications) - их плюс в том, что они отображаются даже при неактивном окне браузера.

---

А когда возможностей уведомлений недостаточно, но при этом хватит отображения только на странице, альтернативой может быть такой вариант: контент-скриптом добавлять на страницу изначально скрытый блок с `position: fixed` и высоким значением `z-index` - и для  отправки команды на показ этого блока (из бэкграунд-скрипта расширения) использовать [передачу сообщений](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).
В сообщениях контент-скрипту можно передавать также и данные - например, когда бэкграунд-скрипт получил информацию от веб-сервиса, и надо вывести ее на странице, в некотором подобии диалога.